# SYMFONY 5.2 : .env variable in messenger.yaml configuration

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

Is there any way to use .env variable in messenger routing?

For example, this configuration:

```
framework:
   messenger:
       transports:
           test: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_TEST)%'
           test1: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_TEST_1)%'
           other: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_OTHER)%'

       routing:
           'App\Message\Oss': '%env(json:ROUTING_OSS)%'
```

give me this error:

```
In Compiler.php line 108:                                                                                             
  Incompatible use of dynamic environment variables "json:ROUTING_OSS" found in parameters.                                                                                            

In FrameworkExtension.php line 1864:                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Invalid Messenger routing configuration: the "App\Message\Oss" class is being routed to a sender called "%env(json:ROUTING_OSS)%". This is not a valid transport or service id.
```

Comment: `%env(json:ROUTING_OSS)%` returns an array, but a string is expected.  Why you need the `json:` environment variable processor?

Comment: @Artem https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#routing-messages-to-a-transport array is also supported (second example 'My\Message\ToBeSentToTwoSenders': [async, audit])